# JFreeChart ChartPanel Zoom in but resume sliding

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to use the dynamic data chart with time in the domain axis, and some integer as the range axis.

When I tried to zoom-in, even if the data chart is still adding in new items, the sliding stops.

Is there a way to enable sliding even though zoomed in using the mouse?

Thanks